# What is the criteria for the V2Dir flag appearing?

Tags: relays, directory, flags, mirrors

I've just read [What are good explanations for relay flags?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/423/1112) to get a feel for what flags could possibly appear on my new relay (which is an image from Tor Cloud, but with `torrc` modified to be a relay instead of a bridge).

I currently have the flags Fast, Running, and Valid. I'm wondering if and when I'll get the V2Dir flag, as I've turned on directory mirroring. Here are the relevant sections of my `torrc` (AFAIK):

```
DirPort 9030
AccountingStart week 1 10:00
AccountingMax 15 GB
BandwidthRate 100MB (104857600)
BandwidthBurst 1GB (1073741824)
ORListenAddress 0.0.0.0:9001
ORPort 443
```

Comment: Is your `DirPort` reachable from the outside and do you see traffic on that port?

Comment: @JensKubieziel according to telnet, nothing's listening or the port's not reachable (not sure which, although the EC2 firewall policy lets traffic through). the question still stands, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get the `V2Dir` flag simply by publishing a DirPort.

Now, whether or not you publish a directory port depends on many factors, including your accounting/hibernation configuration --- see [router.c](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/blob/tor-0.2.4.20:/src/or/router.c#l1018).

Comment: Indeed, this person should have seen a notice-level log explaining "Not advertising DirPort (Reason: AccountingMax enabled)".

Comment: @RogerDingledine sorry, completely missed this comment. I'm not seeing anything like that in ARM (I haven't been keeping ARM open since the Tor daemon started, but I _have_ issued SIGHUP).