# Tor-relay on raspberry : /var/lib/tor

Tags: relays, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I run a *tor* relay on a Raspberry Pi, with ramdisk e.g. used for `/var/lib/tor` and some other folders that see lots of data written, so that the SD card does not see too many writes.

No the folder `/var/lib/tor` sees more and more data stored, until the ramdisk is full and *tor* stops working.

My *tor* version is 0.4.2.7, I've recenty upgraded from an older version (based on `debian stretch`). I've not seen this problem before the upgrade.

Is it possible to avoid that *Tor* uses so much space?
Here are the biggest files and folders:

```
/var/lib/tor/diff-cache 75M
/var/lib/tor/cached-descriptors 60M
/var/lib/tor/cached-descriptors.new 27M
/var/lib/tor/keys 11M
```

**Update (2020-04-21):**

So my settings are now:

```
DirPort 9030 # unchanged
DirCache 0 # new
```

I received once the log message:

```
[warn] DirCache is disabled and we are configured as a relay. We will not become a Guard
```

The `V2DIR` flag for my relay on [Tor Metrics](https://metrics.torproject.org) is gone now.

I'll wait how the folder `/var/lib/tor` fills up and report the results here.

**Update (2020-04-22):**

The memory usage in folder `/var/lib/tor` seems to be stable at 75M (for two days now), so `tor` keeps running without running out of space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to https://metrics.torproject.org/rs.html and search for your relay, does it have the "V2Dir" flag? If so, your relay is acting as a directory cache. In this case you should set `DirCache 0` in your torrc config to prevent your relay from caching extra directory documents that aren't needed for your relay to run.

Comment: indeed, it does and always did so in the past. So acc. to [this thread](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1485/what-is-the-criteria-for-the-v2dir-flag-appearing) I should just remove the `DirPort` line from my `torrc`?

Comment: @radix Your relay will still be used as a directory cache even if you don't set a `DirPort` since clients can build circuits to your relay and download directory documents over these circuits.

Comment: sorry, my edit landed at first in your answer rather then in my quesion...now it seems I can't undo the change in your question.

Comment: @radix If it still ends up using too much storage leave a comment here so I see it and I'll try to think of other things you could change. But disabling the cache should save a lot of space.