# I have 1635 inbound and one outbound connection on my relay is that normal?

Tags: relays

I am running a middle relay on a raspberry pi b+ its been up for about two weeks now and until last night was averaging 50MB downloads a day. Now its finally sped up, hope im not doing something wrong my relay has HSDIR tag on it not sure what that means.

Comment: I'm seeing something similar on my relay-only server. I increased my max bandwidth rate to 8Mbps (from 4 Mbps) and the number of incoming connections (in ARM) went waaaay up....but the number of outgoing connections actually went down. I'm currently sitting on 2114 incoming and 72 outgoing. I'll wait and see if it settles down. But the imbalance does seem odd. Why so many incoming....but so few outgoing? Yours was a generic question about the perceived balance / imbalance between incoming and outgoing connections. The previous responder missed the point of it, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not providing enough information to answer the question but you can always take a look at the status of your relay at [Globe](https://globe.torproject.org/) or [Atlas](https://atlas.torproject.org/). Familiarize yourself with what each of the [flags](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/423/what-are-good-explanations-for-relay-flags) mean, that will help you diagnose if there are issues. HSDir means that you are hosting a portion of the hidden service distributed hash table or the Hidden Service Directory.

You can also make manual circuits to confirm that you can indeed use your relay as a node. This is pretty easy if you're using [STEM](https://stem.torproject.org/tutorials/to_russia_with_love.html#custom-path-selection).