# How a node get a exit flag?

Tags: exit-relays

I read this [article](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/lifecycle-of-a-new-relay) and I understand how a node can become a entry guard but I didn't found documentation about how a node become a exit node?

Where I can found documentations or articles similar to the article about lifecycle of a new node?

I check this [post](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/423/what-are-good-explanations-for-relay-flags). It says for the exit node:

> A router is called an 'Exit’ iff it allows exits to at least two of the ports 80, 443, and 6667 and allows exits to at least one /8 address space.

That means a new node configure it's machine with these ports open and enough adress, it's become automatically a exit node?